# RadGrid Column Sorting on every click of the Header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, telerik-grid

I have a `RadGrid` like below :-

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" 
    OnNeedDataSource="NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="ItemCommand">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
        <CommandItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditSelected" runat="server" CommandName="EditSelected" Visible='<%# RadGrid1.EditIndexes.Count = 0%>'><img style="border:0px;vertical-align:middle;" alt="" src="images/edit.png"/>Edit Selected </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="InitInsert" Visible='<%# Not RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted%>'><img style="border:0px;vertical-align:middle;" alt="" src="images/addrecord.png"/>Add New </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="if ( ! checkRowSelected()) return false;" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteSelected"><img style="border:0px;vertical-align:middle;" alt="" src="images/delete.png"/>Delete Selected </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </CommandItemTemplate> 
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="WebSite" DataTextField="WebSite" DataTextFormatString="{0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="WebSite" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}"
                ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" Target="_blank" >
            </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>      
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Now I want the `Name` Column to be 'sortable' alphabetically so if someone clicks the word "Name", they get alpha and reverse alpha sorting with every other click.

So that the sort order changes(to alternate sort) with every click on the Header "Name".

I have a little idea of sorting the column on Header click. But the same column should be sorted in reverse order on the second time click of the Header (and vice-versa).

Could anyone help me how to accomplish this , or any ideas , ThankYou !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can refer to :-

http://www.telerik.com/forums/multi-column-sorting-when-header-click

There are also other sites that explain well about this.

Thanks a lot !!!